# Word/slang for person who cries easily watching movies

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

I'd like to know from native speakers what would they call or what slang would they use for a person who cries easily watching even the silliest of movies (meaning very little drama). For example, watching Home Alone when Kevin meets his family again.

Comment: Probably I would use a term that refers to someone who cries easily in general: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/346709/191178

Comment: “tears up easily”. to tear up has two meanings, though

Comment: None of the answers are specific to movies—they can apply to anything. But it's not clear what the exact scope or context of this question should be.

Comment: @JasonBassford - Good point.  In all honesty, I meant my answer as a comment, but somehow typed it in the wrong text box.

Comment: What about "a big softie"? Although that's very general and not specific to watching movies.

Answer (score 3):

**an emotional person** is prone to emotions.

[**emotional**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/emotional) - (adjective) "readily affected with or stirred by emotion: an emotional person who often weeps."

Answer (score 3):

I'd normally call them a ***sap***. Meaning someone who is overly emotional and cries at the slightest sad thing.  However I can't find that definition in the dictionaries I looked at.  I will also note that a "sappy" movie is one that plays to one's emotions in an effort to elicit a response- like crying:

For example here's *sappy* used "in the wild" (thanks @Conrado):

> Everyone needs a good cry every now and then. Especially since it’s summer and we have plenty of time on our hands to watch sappy movies, eat chocolates and bury our sorrows.

Source: [identity-mag.com](https://identity-mag.com/need-a-good-cry-check-out-the-sappy-movie-list-we-made-you/)

Comment: Jim, I've suggested an edit showing an example from in the wild using "sappy movie", but SE says now that it has to be approved by trusted community members etc. If the machine doen't ask you to confirm, feel free to reject them anyhow.

Comment: @Conrado- I approved it (with an edit) :-)

Comment: I've never actually heard of *sap* being used to mean somebody overly emotional. (Although *sappy* means sentimental.) But *sap*, as far as I know, just means gullible.

Comment: @JasonBassford - That seems to be confirmed by the dictionaries I looked at, but I can tell you that “calling” someone a sap when they cry at a certain type of “Hallmark channel” movie has been been a common thing in my sphere of experience.

Comment: Perhaps since OP asks for slang, an Urban Dictionary entry is allowed? "**sap**:
someone who is spilling out their guts about how they feel and such." https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sap